# Image mapping on background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website project that needs to emulate the experience of walking trough a set of chambers. Since Flash is obsolete I decided to go with HTML/CSS and JS to achieve this goal.

In order to click the doors I made some image mappings like this:

```
<area
        alt="intrare-lobby"
        title="Intrare"
        shape="poly"
        coords="1257,676,1256,569,1259,565,1268,560,1278,558,1287,558,1293,559,1298,560,1304,564,1306,568,1307,677"
        rel="Intrare Lobby"
        role="link"
/>
```

The problem that I found with image mappings is that the maximum adaptation to the screen's resolution that I can get is to make the image responsive. A responsive image adapts to the width of the page but not to its height.

Since the whole website is build out of an image it makes sense to use those images in CSS, making them background images, with "cover" set as its size.

The website will have a mobile version so this only needs to adapt to screens from tablet resolution upwards.

**I know that image mappings are limited to the  tag. Is there any way I can obtain the same effect with JavaScript on a background image?**

The link to the project is https://sporedev.ro/pleiade2/. I currently have mappings on the statues on the left side and on the entrance doors to the building.